# The Value expression for the text box XXX uses an aggregate expression without a scope

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report '/REPORTNAME' is invalid.

The Value expression for the text box **"Texbox 3"** uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregate used egates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.

**"Texbox 3"** **Contains** : =SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Date.Value),0,1))
**Also : I have 2 datasets**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
=SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Date.Value),0,1),"DataSetName")
```

When you aggregation values outside a tablix, you need to specify the aggregation's context